# Error C2440 and C2973 when using enum as template argument in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++17

I get two errors C2440 and C2973 while compiling this code with visual studio 2019:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

enum class First {
    SOME_VALUE,
    OTHER_VALUE
};

enum class Second {
    PRIME,
    BIS
};


template<First FIRST_VAL>
struct FirstData {
    int i;
};

template<Second SECOND_VAL>
struct SecondData {
    long l;
};

template<First FIRST_VAL,Second SECOND_VAL>
class Data :public SecondData<SECOND_VAL>, public FirstData<FIRST_VAL> {

};

template<First FIRST_VAL>
struct WithFirstData {
    virtual const FirstData<FIRST_VAL >& getData() = 0;
    virtual ~WithFirstData() = default;
};

template<Second SECOND_VAL>
struct WithSecondData {
    virtual const SecondData<SECOND_VAL>& getData() = 0;
    virtual ~WithSecondData() = default;
};

template<First FIRST_VAL, Second SECOND_VAL>
class WithData : public WithFirstData<FIRST_VAL>, public WithSecondData<SECOND_VAL> {

public:
    const First First;
    const Second Second;
private:

    const Data<FIRST_VAL, SECOND_VAL> data;
public:

    virtual const Data<FIRST_VAL, SECOND_VAL>& getData() {
        return data;
    }

    template<typename ... DataArgs>
    WithData(DataArgs &&... data) :First(FIRST_VAL), Second(SECOND_VAL), data(std::forward<DataArgs>(data)...) {    }

    virtual ~WithData() {};
};

class ConcreteWithData : public WithData<First::SOME_VALUE, Second::BIS> {
public:
    ConcreteWithData() : WithData() {
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostream, const ConcreteWithData& o) {
    ostream << static_cast<int>(o.First);
    return ostream;
}
int main() {

    ConcreteWithData ev;
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n" << ev;
}
```

Except from error messages:

```
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(55): error C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from 'int' to 'First'
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(55): message : Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(55): error C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from 'int' to 'Second'
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(55): message : Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(55): error C2973: 'Event': invalid template argument 'int'
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(44): message : see declaration of 'Event'
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(44): error C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from 'int' to 'First'
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(44,36): message : Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(44): error C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from 'int' to 'Second'
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(44,70): message : Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(44,1): error C2973: 'WithSecondData': invalid template argument 'int'
1>C:\[...]\Test.cpp(38): message : see declaration of 'WithSecondData'
```

Funny thing is that this compiles no-problem under gcc (`g++.exe (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0`).
Who is at fault here? me for doing things that shouldn't be understood by compiler; or vs compiler for not understanding enums properly; or gcc for allowing something it should not?

EDIT 2:

This compiles if I refactor it to unscoped enums and ints as template arguments, so a work-around is there, but I would love to be able to use scoped enums. And, more importantly, I would love to understand what went wrong in a first place.

EDIT 1:

The original code was a bit bigger I boiled it down a bit, but basically what I wanted to achieve was to have specializations with diferent data for FirstData and SecondData based on diferent enum values. So then I could use references to `WithFirstData<SOME_VALUE>` `WithSecondData<PRIME>` when refering to diferent concrete implementations and be sure that those implementations have the data i am looking for.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me, what you're trying to achive with that code. Mind to elaborate that in your question a bit please?

Comment: Your code has many other problems, but it does look like a compiler bug.  clang and gcc do compile after fixing errors.

Comment: I suggest that you could submit this question to [Microsoft DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** See the solution at https://godbolt.org/z/ez1K43z8T.

I know that this is a pretty old question at this point, but since I recently came across the same issue in one of my projects, I wanted to discuss my findings and a potential workaround for others who may be experiencing similar problems.

The first thing to note is the fact that, as was mentioned in the comments by another user, this appears to be a bug with the MSVC. I cannot elaborate on *why* it happens, since I don't work on the compiler myself, but from my own findings, it seems to be internally converting scoped enums to their underlying types.

Let's take a closer look at one of the compiler's error messages:

```
C:\[...]\Test.cpp(55): error C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from 'int' to 'First'
C:\[...]\Test.cpp(55): message : Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
```

For some inexplicable reason, the MSVC is attempting to convert an `int` value to an enumeration value from the scoped enum `First`. Why is it doing it from an `int` variable, though? That's because `int` is the default underlying type of a scoped enum:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::to_underlying_t<First>, int>);  // The assertion succeeds!
```

So, as a workaround, here is a C++20 concept which compares two types, with at least one of them being an enumeration, and checks to see if the MSVC would consider them "equivalent" for the sake of working around this issue:

```
template <typename LHSType, typename RHSType>
concept IsEnumEquivalent = (std::is_enum_v<LHSType> && !std::is_enum_v<RHSType> && std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type_t<LHSType>, RHSType>) ||
    (std::is_enum_v<RHSType> && !std::is_enum_v<LHSType> && std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type_t<RHSType>, LHSType>) ||
    (std::is_enum_v<LHSType> && std::is_enum_v<RHSType> && std::is_same_v<LHSType, RHSType>);
```

Then, you could define your `FirstData` and `SecondData` structs like so:

```
template <IsEnumEquivalent<First> FIRST_TYPE, FIRST_TYPE FIRST_VAL>
struct FirstData 
{
    static constexpr int i = 0;
};

template <IsEnumEquivalent<Second> SECOND_TYPE, SECOND_TYPE SECOND_VAL>
struct SecondData 
{
    static constexpr long l = 0;
};
```

along with any explicit template specializations:

```
template <>
struct FirstData<First, First::SOME_VALUE>
{
    static constexpr int i = 5;
};

// Continue defining explicit specializations...
```

That's about it for working around the MSVC bug. However, since you mentioned a more specific problem, I'll discuss how this solution could be used to solve it. As the OP mentioned, the goal was for concrete implementations to have access to specific data, presumably defined at compile time. (If the data should be modifiable at runtime, then template metaprogramming probably isn't the answer you were looking for in the first place.)

An interesting thing to note is that our concept `IsEnumEquivalent` will accept `int` values, should the user wish to provide them. Considering that the whole point of this was to make use of the type safety of scoped enums, it would be nice to prevent this. One way to do this is as follows:

```
namespace IMPL
{
    template <IsEnumEquivalent<First> FIRST_TYPE, FIRST_TYPE FIRST_VAL, IsEnumEquivalent<Second> SECOND_TYPE, SECOND_TYPE SECOND_VAL>
    struct WithDataIMPL
    {
        static constexpr FirstData<FIRST_TYPE, FIRST_VAL> FirstDataElement{};
        static constexpr SecondData<SECOND_TYPE, SECOND_VAL> SecondDataElement{};
    };
}

template <First FIRST_VAL, Second SECOND_VAL>
using WithData = IMPL::WithDataIMPL<First, FIRST_VAL, Second, SECOND_VAL>;
```

Essentially, we are defining `WithData` as a type alias for an implementation structure contained within the `IMPL` namespace. This is my personal convention for organizing implementation details; most other projects I find call this the `details` namespace or something similar. Regardless of the convention you adopt, the idea is that implementation details are hidden from API users.

If you are using C++20 modules, then you can actually prevent other modules from ever seeing these implementation details by choosing not to export them! However, if you are still using traditional header files, then you will just have to ignore whatever details inevitably leak into other source files.

Anyways, going back to the original problem, we can define a "concrete implementation" class as follows:

```
class ConcreteWithData : public WithData<First::SOME_VALUE, Second::BIS> 
{
    // Do whatever you want with ConcreteWithData here. However, if you don't
    // plan on adding anything else to this class, then it may be better to just
    // make it a type alias:
    //
    // using ConcreteWithData = WithData<First::SOME_VALUE, Second::BIS>;
};
```

Accessing its data is then done as follows:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostream, const ConcreteWithData& o) 
{
    ostream << o.FirstDataElement.i << '\n';
    ostream << o.SecondDataElement.l << '\n';

    return ostream;
}
```

Wow, this post ended up being a *lot* longer than I was expecting it to be. Hopefully, it ends up being helpful to others who are/were experiencing the same issue as the OP was. If you want more details, the following Godbolt link includes a more detailed description of this solution as it pertains to this particular problem: https://godbolt.org/z/ez1K43z8T.